# Database Diffing tool/library

Tags: database, diff, postgresql

I have a testing database and a production database. I want to update/insert the changes that i did in the testing database.

I already read this post about database diffing:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804779/how-to-check-difference-between-two-databases-in-postgresql

I checked all the tools and found them not very appealing -> The main reason is that they are bloated and often confusing + i can not integrate them into my existing API.

So i'm looking for a tool/library that I can integrate into my existing Spring Boot API.

What are your recommendations?

---

I might need to explain a bit more what we are doing.

I am creating a Landing management system: With some JSON configuration I'm able to create Landingpages out of reusable React components.

These configuration should be done in a testing environment to see if the landingpages work. Then the configuration should be "transmitted" to the live database. Therefore it would be optimal to have a database diffing tool.

If you have other solutions to this problem it would be also good :)

Comment: By the way, prevention is a better route, using a database migration tool such as [**Flyway**](https://flywaydb.org) or Liquibase to automatically update a database instance with your intended changes. Diffing on a database is not a simple matter.

Comment: I agree with Basil. Diff'ing should be a one-time thing because it can never reliably work. I would **never** trust any diff'ing tool for production rollout of my changes. There is no way around using a proper schema migration tool like [Liquibase](http://liquibase.org/) or Flyway. Liquibase can be integrated into your Java program. For a proper migration setup just as well as for a one-shot diff

Comment: See my edit please

Comment: So you want to "diff" the data (=content) not the structure?

Comment: Yes - i would like to diff the data (content)